# Is “mustn’t be doing something” deontic or epistemic?

Tags: modal-verbs, deontic-vs-epistemic

Do the following sentences have a deontic or epistemic meaning?

> - He must be studying now.
> - He mustn't be studying now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linguistic modality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality#Epistemic_vs._deontic_modality) entry on Wikipedia:

> In English as in many other languages, some of the same words are used for deontic modality as for epistemic modality, and **the meaning is distinguished from context**: He must be there by now (epistemic) versus He must be there tomorrow at noon (deontic).

(emphasis mine)

So each sentence could be either deontic or epistemic based on context.

Comment: I wonder if, with *must*, the progressive "studying" is used more often with the epistemic, and the bare infinitive with the deontic.  I wouldn't say "She must be studying" when I meant "She should really study now, not be wasting time by watching TV."

Comment: @TRomano still context-based. Counterexample to your example: "She **must be studying** by 10pm or she's grounded".

Comment: Agreed. That "by 10pm" makes all the difference.

Comment: In BrE, the epistemic meaning of ""He can't be studying now".